# Python Mail Parser with Beautifulsoup - Struggling to parse entire Inbox

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am a newbie in the python world and would love some help with an email parser I am trying to write.

I have a mailbox that only contains email with a HTML table in the body (all messages are formatted the same way).

I want to parse the entire mailbox and extract the data in each HTML table so it can be saved as a single csv file.

I have managed to connect to mailbox, pull down the last email and successfully parse the table and save it into a csv file.

I am now trying to loop through all the emails in the inbox and extract the data from each table into the csv file but I don't know where to begin.

Could anybody offer some advice please ?

My code so far is :

```
import imaplib
from email.parser import BytesParser, Parser
from email.policy import default
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER = 'USERNAME' #Removed for this post 
PASSWORD ='PASSWORD' #Removed for this post 

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('MAILSERVER') #Removed for this post 
mail.login(USER, PASSWORD)
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]


email_message = BytesParser(policy=default).parsebytes(raw_email)

simplest = email_message.get_body(preferencelist=('html'))
htmlcontent = simplest.get_content()

data = []
list_header =[]

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table")

output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        relevant = column.text.replace('\n', '')
        relevant2 = relevant.replace('\xa0', '')
        output_row.append(relevant2)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

print (output_rows) 
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

What I have done so far is probably not the best / most professional way of doing it but as I say I have only just started learning python.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation for imaplib comes with an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example) which could have helped you

just read the full result of your request:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
for num in data[0].split():
    result, data = mail.uid('fetch', num, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = data[0][1]
```

you'll have to reindent the rest your code (or use functions, which is way better)